# Comparing two columns based on user input

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

| blank | Domain | Village | Town |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Church | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| Armory | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| Pigsty | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| Palace | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

Let's say I have something similar to the chart above (only with way more columns and rows). On another tab, I have two dropdowns, each with Domain/Village/Town as options. Below those dropdowns is a list of all the buildings (Church/Armory/Pigsty/Palace).

For what I would like to do, let's say I have the following input:

Domain -- Town

The ideal output would be to change the cell color of the buildings according to how the True/false changes between the input options.

Church: Green (True -> True)

Armory: Blue (False -> True)

Pigsty: Orange (True -> False)

Palace: Red (False -> False)

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Edit:- able copy of the sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4bs6bHC9njVRkNqhQ-gKFtbOro6_MjbzR2OeNBZpvY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Plenty of *"let's say"*. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4bs6bHC9njVRkNqhQ-gKFtbOro6_MjbzR2OeNBZpvY/edit?usp=sharing

Here's an editable copy

Comment: Thank you for the sheet. Had a look at it. I found no formulas or rules at all. What have you tried so far? Also, I still cannot see what you need. Sorry :(

Comment: So each organization has a list of valid buildings. This chart of organizations x buildings is on Reference2 tab. In the Buildings tab, the user will select their current organization on A2. On B2, they put in what they're changing to. Thus, the list of valid buildings they can use can change. The building list below should reflect that change in what's allowed: Green if they're valid for both orgs, Red if they're invalid for both, Blue if they're gaining an allowed building, orange if they're losing one.

I'm trying to figure out which formulas/cond formatting to use to achieve this.